# Promise's reject is throwing Error in angular 2/4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular-promise

I have defined a async validator function like this.

```
static shouldBeUnique(control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (control.value === 'some_text') {
                resolve({ shouldBeUnique: true });
            }
            reject(null);
        }, 2000);
    });
}
```

Its throwing below error (may be on **reject**)

> Cannot read property 'ngOriginalError' of null

How to get rid of this error?
Thanks

Plnkr : https://embed.plnkr.co/VSHXGKiMGUWEhy8neyXU/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally if you reject a Promise you should better reject it with an `Error`

```
reject(new Error('User is not vikash (whatever descriptive message what went wrong)'));
```

**EDIT** Since you are trying to implement async validator you need to `resolve` a Promise with `null` not to reject it to indicate validation was ok.

```
static shouldBeUnique(control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (control.value === 'some_text') {
              resolve({ shouldBeUnique: true });
            } else {
              resolve(null); // resolve
            }
        }, 2000);
    });
}
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/VOnfqKX3rPGq6EZbjKu0?p=preview)

Comment: @VikashVerma Could you recreate the issue using say plnkr.co or any other service you like?

Comment: @VikashVerma Check updated answer and demo https://plnkr.co/edit/VOnfqKX3rPGq6EZbjKu0?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

In angular form validation, when the field is valid you should pass null. It's a little bit confusing but that's how it goes. You can read more about [here](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators) and [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html).

I'm attaching plunker I've forked from you. I've only changed that null will be return when the filed is valid, and [ValidationErrors](https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidationErrors) when it's invalid.
Also to be more clear about the filed validation status Iv'e added to the html the errors object of the filed.

https://embed.plnkr.co/t0gniM/

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      Please open developer console to chek the exception <br>
      Type anything and click anywhere other than the textbox<br><br>

      <form [formGroup]="formObj">
      <input type="text" id="username" formControlName="username" placeholder="Username" />
      {{formObj.controls['username'].errors|json}}

      </form>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  shouldBeUnique(control:AbstractControl):Promise<ValidationErrors|null>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (control.value === 'vikash') {
                  console.log('---matched--');
                    resolve(null);
                }else{
                resolve({ shouldBeUnique: true });
                }
            }, 1000);
        });
  }

  formObj = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required
    ], [
      this.shouldBeUnique
      ])
  });
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Hopes it's help's.

Comment: For a clean code, shouldBeUnique should be part of a username.validators.ts validator file - and not part of the same app component. 1 thing you spoted right is the separation of asynchronous and synchronous validations here:     username: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required
    ], [
      this.shouldBeUnique
      ])